# Pydiction support of custom decorators in its static analysis

Tags: python, vim-plugin

I've installed `pydiction` for Vim and got it working.  For reference, its Vim script home is here: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=850

The way to call the `pydiction.py` static analysis script is:

`python pydiction.py root.my.submodule`

once the location of the `root` module is already put in your PYTHONPATH variable.  This all works fine, and I've been able to analyze a lot of my project's modules and get the tags added to the `complete-dict` file where pydiction looks when you're doing the tab completion in Vim.

In my project, there's a custom defined decorator, `@innerclass`, which lives in a `innerclass.py` file, the directory of which has been successfully analyzed and tagged by pydiction.

But when I try to analyze another directory in my project, I get a traceback that seems to indicate a `SyntaxError` on the class definition line that comes just after use of the `@innerclass` decorator.  So it doesn't appear that pydiction knows about the decorator.

Does pydiction just not support custom decorators?  Or is there something I can look for in the definition of the decorator that may be awry?